# Re-sampling and interpolating data using pandas from a given date column to a different date column

Tags: pandas, date, resampling

I can mostly find conversions and down/upsampling from e.g. daily date range to monthly date ranges or from monthly/yearly date ranges to daily date ranges using pandas.

Is there a way that given data for some arbitrary days one can map them to different days using interpolation/extrapolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Index.union`, `reindex`, and `interpolate`

#### MCVE

Create toy data.  Three rows every other day.

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='2D')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 3, 5]), tidx)

df

            A
2018-01-01  1
2018-01-03  3
2018-01-05  5
```

New index for those days in between

```
other_tidx = pd.date_range(tidx.min(), tidx.max()).difference(tidx)
```

---

### Solution

Create a new index that is the union of the old index and the new index

```
union_idx = other_tidx.union(df.index)
```

When we `reindex` with this we get

```
df.reindex(union_idx)

              A
2018-01-01  1.0
2018-01-02  NaN
2018-01-03  3.0
2018-01-04  NaN
2018-01-05  5.0
```

We see the gaps we expected.  Now we can use `interpolate`.  But we need to use the argument `method='index'` to ensure we interpolate relative to the size of the gaps in the index.

```
df.reindex(union_idx).interpolate('index')

              A
2018-01-01  1.0
2018-01-02  2.0
2018-01-03  3.0
2018-01-04  4.0
2018-01-05  5.0
```

And now those gaps are filled.

We can reindex again to reduce to just the other index values

```
df.reindex(union_idx).interpolate('index').reindex(other_tidx)

              A
2018-01-02  2.0
2018-01-04  4.0
```